# Java.net.SocketTimeoutException when running a feature file in Karate

Tags: karate

When running my feature file i get this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I have tried to add a readTimeout by i get the same exception all the time.

```
* configure readTimeout = 10000
```

Do you guys have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no. best option for you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by switching karate-jersey with karate-apache in the pom.xml .